# Jmeter Web Driver - how to start WDS on an existing Chrome session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to start Jmeter and connect to an existing Google Chrome instance to validate a web request.
I've added in Jmeter these elements:

```
jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config
jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler
```

but I don't find a code to put in the WebDriver Sampler to do that.
Can someone help me on that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is [not possible](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18)

---

What you can do is to store [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) from the "existing Google Chrome" instance or use Chrome with [some existing profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) instead of creating a new one.

Also you can "validate a web request" using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, there is no need to connect to the browser. The browser session can be simulated using aforementioned approach with cookies, in JMeter you can set cookies using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)